# bootstrap second colum overlaps first column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following structure of bootstrap. I have 10 | 2 columns but second column overlaps first column, I have cross css properties and remove wrapper also but it still keeps over lapping first column as show in image below
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">Left Column</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
        <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red; height: 500px;">right Column</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

Width `float:left;` to right column is comes as shown in image below on tablet

[image]

Comment: what's the problem in your code, https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7077/

Comment: What is this pl-0 class?

Comment: It only works for me if i add height to `<div class="col-md-10">` other wise it overlaps for some reason

Comment: `.pl-0{padding-left:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

use float:letf in div

right Column

Comment: I had tried that also, It hides left-colum by almost 80 percent. on left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-right:0">Left Column</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 pl-0"  style="padding-left:0">
        <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red; height: 500px;">right Column</div>
</div>
```

or

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10" >Left Column</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 pl-0" >
            <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red; height: 500px;">right Column</div>
    </div>
```

Try this..